# 4G data monitor?

Tags: data-monitoring

I have seen, and have used several data monitors to see my data usage. This is not strictly necessary, as I am on Sprint and have an unlimited data plan. But in my searching, I have not been able to find a data monitor that monitors Sprint's **4G** (WIMAX) data, along with 3G and WiFi. Does one exist? And if it doesn't, does anyone know why it hasn't been done?

**Note:** so far i've used [PhoneUsage](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jupiterapps.phoneusage&feature=search_result), [NetCounter](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.jaqpot.netcounter&feature=search_result), [DroidStats](https://market.android.com/details?id=nitro.phonestats&feature=search_result), and [My Data Manager Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&feature=search_result)

The funny thing is, at least DroidStats and PhoneUsage both say in the information that they only do 2G/3G data. I can't even find an app that lists 4G data in the description.

Comment: Do you want an app that monitors the total 4G data used, the total 3G data used, and the total Wi-Fi used? Or do you want an app that can just tell when 4G data is being used and count it towards the total overall data usage?

Comment: Either. i already have an app to monitor 3G and Wifi, and an app that kept track of all 3 would be good, but if it only does 4G, that'd be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now (unless someone can correct me) there is no APP that will monitor Sprint 4G WiMax data.

Although, it can be found by calling information ***4** from a Sprint phone and pressing **4** to hear details of the individual phone use. The 4G data will be listed, and can be sent in a text message to the phone (if desired) by pressing **2**.

Comment: One remark: ICS (Android 4.0) has a built-in data monitor.

Comment: keeping my fingers crossed for EVO ICS ports :)

Answer (score 5):

First, let me say that network data counting in Android is not so easy, because there is no API which provides this information in a clean way. The App developers have to work with some Linux internals and other issues. This is why most traffic counting Apps don't work on every hardware/software combination. For exaple I had an app that worked with Eclair but stopped working with Gingerbread on my Galaxy S.

Android introduced Long Term Evolution (4G) support with API level 11 (Honeycomb). Most traffic counters read their volume information from the underlying linux network interface. AFAIK there are only two interfaces, one for Wifi and one 2G/3G/4G, which means:

- It will be hard to monitor 4G data separated from 2G/3G
- If a app says it monitors 2G/3G it's very likely that this also includes 4G
- Androids 4G API is relatively new. Support, including separate traffic counting (if it's possible), will hit the apps in the near future.

Here is an example listing that shows the interfaces and their traffic on my Galaxy S. **pdp0 is the mobile** and **eth0 is the wifi** iterface:

```
Interface name: lo
Bytes in: 204335770
Bytes out: 204335770

Interface name: svnet0
Bytes in: 669002
Bytes out: 38238

Interface name: ifb0
Bytes in: 0
Bytes out: 0

Interface name: ifb1
Bytes in: 0
Bytes out: 0

Interface name: usb0
Bytes in: 0
Bytes out: 0

Interface name: sit0
Bytes in: 0
Bytes out: 0

Interface name: ip6tnl0
Bytes in: 0
Bytes out: 0

Interface name: eth0
Bytes in: 9981470
Bytes out: 3524023

Interface name: pdp0
Bytes in: 1421620
Bytes out: 361198
```

Comment: apps that say they monitor 2G/3G don't monitor 4G (to my knowledge) and i would assume it's because it's a different type of signal. And even if something just gave me the total count of 2G/3G/4G, i'd be okay with it, but nothing i've encountered does that.

Comment: I forgot to ask, by 4G do you mean WiMax or LTE? I can mean both and my answer goes for LTE.

Comment: good question! WiMax, i've got Sprint

Answer (score 0):

I use NetCounter. It separates the Wi-Fi data usage from the 3G/4G data usage, and so far it has been very accurate (at least on the mobile data).

Comment: "NetCounter is a simple network traffic counter for EDGE/3G and Wi-Fi." no 4G tracking :/

Comment: Hmmm... Well somehow it works with my phone. I use it for 3G and 4G tracking. The count on NetCounter is actually 1 MB more than what my carrier says I have used, so it is accurate in that respect. However, I'm not using 4G, I'm using H+, which is AT&Ts version of '4G'

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Sprint's 4G :/ i only had 4G on and used many internet apps sequentially and refreshed NetCounter after each one, and never got anything.

Comment: Ah well worth a try I guess. Sorry about that. If I come across anything I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Stats Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebastian.stats) app. It shows 4G data in addition to 2G/3G and Wi-Fi.